# Why is $ |x-\mu|^\alpha+|x-\mu|^n=\Theta(|x|^n)$ at $x \to \infty$?

Tags: limits, asymptotics

I'm currently studying a proof and don't see why the following holds true.

Let $n \ge \alpha > 0, I \subseteq \mathbb R$ and $x, \mu \in I$.

Why is \begin{equation*} |x-\mu|^\alpha+|x-\mu|^n=\Theta(|x|^n)\end{equation*} at $x \to \infty$?

And also why do we have \begin{equation*} |x-\mu|^\alpha+|x-\mu|^n=\Theta(|x-\mu|^\alpha)\end{equation*} at $x \to \mu$?

Comment: Obviously $x-\mu \sim x$ so your question reduces to asking why $x^a + x^b \in \Theta(x^a)$ for $a \ge b$, which just follows by dividing by $x^a$ and taking limits

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Thanks! And for the 2nd one? We have $x-\mu \sim 0$, so $|x-\mu|^n$ becomes neglibly small because $n \ge \alpha$?

Comment: That is the correct intuition. Recall that for $x \in (0,1)$, the function $x^n$ approaches $0$ more rapidly as $n$ increases. As $x \to \mu$ we have $x - \mu \to 0$ so eventually $|x - \mu| < 1$